# Need to use for each in choose in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a requirement where I need to use for each only for when condition in choose in xslt.

```
Input:`<input>baz</input>
<input>haz</input>
<input>nan</input>`
```

XSLT:

```
`<xsl:choose> 
<xsl:for-each select="input">
<xsl:when test="input='haz'">
<output>true</output>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:otherwise>
<output>false</output>
</xsl:otherwise>`
```

any help is really appreciated.

Comment: No, only it has to be either <output>true<output> or <output>false<output>. Sry the <input> can have any of them.

Comment: You don't have a requirement to use particular coding constructs. You have a requirement to produce particular output from particular input. Tell us about the input and required output, and we'll tell you what code you need to write.

Answer (score 1):

Given a **well-formed** input such as:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <input>baz</input>
    <input>haz</input>
    <input>nan</input>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:choose> 
            <xsl:when test="input='haz'">true</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose> 
    </output>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>true</output>
```

---

P.S.

If you like, you could shorten the stylesheet to just:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="input='haz'"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```